# Insufficient information to create shipping label(s) Magento Enterprise

Tags: shipping, fedex

I am using Magento Enterprise 1.14.0.1 
I have Fedex Shiiping method activated and have entered in the information for production that was provided and confirmed by Fedex to be correct for the account ID, Meter, Password, and the key. I have sandbox set to no since the credentials are for production. I have a Max package weight set packaging set to "Your Packaging" and the "drop off" set to regular pickup as we have a driver that comes everyday.

My issue is when I click the button to create a shipment and then enter the total weight and then add the product and click the check box and add the product to the shipment. I then click OK and get an error message that says

Insufficient information to create shipping label(s). Please verify your Store Information and Shipping Settings.

I do not know what to check to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento requires below data to generate shipping labels.

1. Admin First Name
2. Admin Last Name
3. Store Name
4. Store Phone
5. Origin Street Address
6. Origin City
7. Origin Region/State
8. Origin Zip
9. Origin Country

You will see the error if any of the above is missing.

**Navigate to**

`System -> Configuration -> Shipping Settings` to update Origin fields

`System -> Configuration -> General` to update store name & phone

Comment: Yup, all the information was needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Magento requires the shipping information to be in the Shipping Settings.Your store also needs the phone number filled in, plus the store’s City, State (Region), Zip/postal, Country, and store name.  Any of those missing may have caused the error you see. This solved for me. Check [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/mem/viewreply/423258/)