# Create shipping Label using USPS on magento order

Tags: magento-1.9, usps

When we are going to create shipment from admin->orders->Ship->Create Shipping Label. It gives following errors.

> Insufficient information to create shipping label(s). Please verify your Store Information and Shipping Settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46368/insufficient-information-to-create-shipping-labels-magento-enterprise

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala I was set it already.

Comment: Please check debug.log.

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala Now it says "API Authorization failure. User 139NATUR2826 is not authorized to use API SignatureConfirmationV3."